# Symfony, ElasticSearch and custom types

Tags: elasticsearch, symfony, foselasticabundle

In a new feature of our application, we have to display complex table views (which display informations of 5+ entities on every line) and let the user being able to search inside every element.

Let's say we have a SQL Database with basic utilisation of the FosElasticaBundle meaning our ElasticSearch indexing is being linked to our DB.
I'm not sure what's the best case scenario we can put in place. I was going for a custom type with custom providers/finders but i'm not sure if it's a good idea.

There are cases where the informations displayed to the user is just too complex for a strict mapping and i'm looking for the best way to handle this in SF/ES (just like we could do a MySQL View to make it possible at a MySQL Level).

Answer (score 0):

For a similar scenario I use parent child relations between Elastic search documents, and then move de complexity to the queries. Depending on how complex your queries are, this can become a terrible headache.

Other option is to serialize everything in a single document. This, generally speaking, makes queries simpler, but in the other hand you must take care of keeping all the related entities updated.

I have used both. I think the most correct one is the first one, but if your child entities doesn't change I find the second easier.

Going back to the Doctrine domain from the ElasticSearch results, take some time to evaluate the performance. Sometimes is better doing a ElasticaToModel transformer with the needed joins to avoid that lazy loading ruins your performance.